# Using CatalogResolver with StAX

Tags: java, stax, catalog, dtd, xml

I'm using the approach provided here: http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html

Here's my XML parsing code using StAX

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, "true");
CatalogResolver cr = new CatalogResolver();
factory.setXMLResolver(cr);
XMLEventReader eventReader =
    factory.createXMLEventReader(new InputStreamReader(
        httpResp.getEntity().getContent()));
```

However, I cannot give `CatalogResolver` argument to `setXMLResolver()`.
I receive cast exception when I try to cast it to `XMLResolver`.

I'm I missing something ? What other way do I provide a `CatalogResolver` ?

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver` implements `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver` and can therefore be used as resolver for SAX XML parsers.

But `XMLInputFactory` expects a `javax.xml.stream.XMLResolver` which is a different interface.

You could simple wrap your CatalogResolver:

```
CatalogResolver catResolver = null;
XMLResolver xmlResolver = (p,s,b,n) -> { try {
        return catResolver.resolveEntity(p,s);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new XMLStreamException(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... Considering that they are entirely different interfaces, even if I wrap it somehow, will I get the desired effect ?

Comment: Can you please explain your code from a basic Java perspective..? I've had little luck in attempting to wrap the `CatalogResolver`